# manual pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I want to add laravel paginator for my select query:
the below query is working fine but not able to add laravel paginator.

```
    $results = DB::select('SELECT
    distances.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(23.0376279 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(72.5102283 ) ) + sin( radians(23.0376279 ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
        shopdatabase.shop_product.stock,
        shopdatabase.shop_product.price AS price,
        shopdatabase.shops.id AS shopId,
        shopdatabase.product.name AS name,
        shopdatabase.product.id AS productId,
        shopdatabase.shops.name AS shopName,
        shopdatabase.shop_product.status,
        shopdatabase.product_image.title AS image,
        shopdatabase.product_meta.metaValue AS sourceDetails,
        shopdatabase.product.sourceUrl
     FROM
        shopdatabase.shop_product
        INNER JOIN shopdatabase.shops
         ON shopdatabase.shop_product.shopId = shopdatabase.shops.id
        INNER JOIN shopdatabase.product
         ON shopdatabase.shop_product.productId = shopdatabase.product.id
        INNER JOIN shopdatabase.product_image
         ON shopdatabase.shop_product.productId = shopdatabase.product_image.productId
        INNER JOIN shopdatabase.product_meta
         ON shopdatabase.shop_product.productId = shopdatabase.product_meta.productId
     WHERE
        shopdatabase.shop_product.status = "active") distances
WHERE
    distance < 20
ORDER BY
    distance ASC');
```

Or can you tell me how can i write this select query with Eloquent?
That will be good if we can write the above code with Eloquent.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. First - use eloquent relations.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent is often not the best choice for more complex queries.

As earlier commenters have mentioned you might be able to refine this by establishing your relations.

However you should be able to paginate query builder results using paginate().

```
DB::select($query)->paginate(25);
```

Another option is to use slice() on a collection.

```
$collection = DB::select($query)->get();
$collection->slice(($currentPage-1) * $size, $size);
```

Then you need if you need a paginator to create links etc. you can create a paginator manually.

```
new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $collection,
            $total,
            $size,
            $currentPage
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read through the Laravel documentation for Eloquent and learn how to use relationships correctly.

Check out this resource: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Once you set up your model relationships you should then be able to call the paginate method as specified here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

You should be able to use something like this:

```
$foo->with('bar')->paginate();
```